# Can an SMTP server respond with a failure such as 552?

Tags: smtp, mandrill

We use Mandrill to send emails and we are wondering about SMTP responses with respect to messages that cannot be delivered. For example, 552 occurs when the recipient's mailbox is full.

It only takes a few seconds for the SMTP server to respond. Within that time, does the message get to the recipient's mailbox?

If so, what happens if the mail cannot be delivered immediately? Is there a timeout such that the SMTP server responds even when the email is not delivered?

Answer (score 1):

> It only takes a few seconds for the SMTP server to respond. Within
> that time, does the message get to the recipient's mailbox?

If the server sends an error because the mailbox is full, that is a good indication that the message did not get to the recipient's mailbox.

> If so, what happens if the mail cannot be delivered immediately? Is
> there a timeout such that the SMTP server responds even when the email
> is not delivered?

It depends on what server you are connecting to.  If you are connecting directly to the destination server (e.g. an Exchange server), it will often know whether it can accept the email or not (e.g. because the the mailbox is full), and can respond immediately by refusing delivery.

If you are connecting to an MTA which routes the email to another mail server, then it will not know whether the recipient's mailbox is full when you connect to it.  However, it may reject the email for other reasons (like if your IP address has a reputation for sending spam).  The MTA will usually accept the entire message before attempting to pass the email message to another mail server.

If the MTA attempts to deliver the email and receives a permanent (5xx) error, then the MTA will not try to deliver the email again.  If the error is a transient (4xx) error, then the MTA usually waits a little while and then tries to deliver the mail again.  Most MTAs will have a timeout set, after which they stop trying to deliver mail.

Most modern MTAs support DSN as an SMTP extension.  (DSN stands for Delivery Status Notification: see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3461 for details.)  When an MTA that supports DSN cannot deliver an email to a recipient, it sends a DSN message to the sender indicating that it could not deliver the email.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK for authenticated/trusted senders most SMTP server deploy "accept and store in queue before any forward attempt".

If you want more detailed info the name SMTP server soft you use.